Xdebug extension not getting recognized by PHP
Some of the code I'm working with uses PHP 5.2.6, which is very old and I'm not sure if it's possible to get Xdebug working alongside it.
I have updated my php.ini file as follows:
zend_extension="C:\php_server\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_mode = req

This is what I could find online as far as documentation goes. I've dropped the earliest listed release on their historical releases page. Tried just about everything to get this to work, but still struggling. Is it just a case of my PHP version being too old?

What xdebug version is it? You may go way back to a 2.x version.

Xdebug v2.0.0, I tried to grab the earliest version I could.

I highly recommend you use the Installation Wizard.

PHP 5.2 is definitely too old. It became unsupported (by the PHP development team) on Jan 2011 (13 years, 4 months ago). You really must upgrade.
I recommend you pick Xdebug 2.2.7 — the latest with PHP 5.2 support:
https://xdebug.org/download/historical#2_2_7
There are a few differences between Xdebug 2.2.0 (compiled for MS VC6) and 2.2.7 (compiled for MS VS9), and if you have this misaligned with PHP, it won't load. You can use phpinfo() to find out which VC version your windows compile of PHP is using.
It will also say whether it is a thread-safe version of PHP or not. If it is the former, you need the binary that has the "TS" label, otherwise you must use the one that does not have the TS label.

Unfortunately working on a legacy system project at work, so don't have the luxury of upgrading my PHP version :( Thanks for taking the time to reply.
